# Extraction of nth array in a loop

Tags: python, arrays

```
    for j in range(50):
     s = random.sample(xrange(1,50),5)
     e = random.sample(xrange(1,1000),5)
     print s
     print e
     d = [a*b for a,b in zip(s,e)]
     past_network = ap.log2(d)
     print past_network
```

Above code will generate 50 arrays.

How can I extract it's 26th array for further calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Use `if j==25` inside the loop:

```
for j in range(50):
    ##
    ## your lines
    ##
    if j == 25:
       my_26th = d
```

`25` not `26` because the range of `j` starts from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just an if..else statement in the loop would do:

```
import random

for j in range(50):
    s = random.sample(xrange(1,50),5)
    e = random.sample(xrange(1,1000),5)
    #print s
    #print e
    d = [a * b for a, b in zip(s, e)]
    if j == 25:
        #do whatever you want to do
        print d
    #past_network = ap.log2(d)
    #print past_network
```

The above code will print the 26th array. 
 
You can remove the comments in your piece of code, it was just for me to avoid errors (caused by ap.log2(d)) and some mess while printing.